# Create Exception Event in a recurring event using REST call in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I have created a recurring event in Microsoft Outlook using REST call... Say for example the recurring event has 5 occurrence.. I wish to change the title of the 3rd instance alone.. How can I achieve it using REST call.?

Is it possible to use PATCH with the event id of the child event..

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as [editing an occurence in a recurrence event in outlook calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815649/editing-an-occurence-in-a-recurrence-event-in-outlook-calendar). Each instance has it's own ID which you can use in a PATCH request.