# editing an occurence in a recurrence event in outlook calendar

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, recurrence, outlook-restapi

I have edited only one event in a recurrence series. While I send a get request with delta token I will get the seriesmaster content, and the edited occurence with type exception

My question is how do I patch these kind of events.what is the attribute to add the exception date

Comment: Hi @Harini, I am stuck in a similar situation. Would you please share what was the solution did you apply? I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an exception, you would need to modify (via PATCH) the instance you want to become the exception.

If you do:

```
GET /me/events/{event-id-of-master}/instances?startDateTime={start}&endDateTime={end}
```

You get back a list of instances in the recurrence that fall between `start` and `end`. You'll notice that each instance has it's own ID. Using that ID, you PATCH the instance just like patching any other non-recurring event:

```
PATCH /me/events/{id-of-instance}
```

Comment: Hi @Jason, I am updating an existing outlook calendar viewing feature in our custom application that displays everything except recurrence. Since I am new to this, I am aggressively learning how to implement and integrate it with the current system. I realized that we have a property caller event.Recurrence that will hold the RecurrencePatter and RecurrenceRange. I have saved these values in the database. So, I can build events on the fly. However, there's a case when a single event of recurring series can be updated on the outlook calendar. I don't know how to interpret that. Can U plz help?